# Page scrolls up in virtual keyboard's presence in iphone

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, mobile-safari

I have a chatting application page in my website. The main container takes full height and width on mobile devices. The container has `position: fixed` and 3 `divs` inside it have `position:absolute`. The last div `#app-msg-composer` has a `textarea` and send `button` inside it like other chat applications. Below is the brief code:

```
<div id='app-container'>
    <div id='app-header'></div>
    <div id='app-body'></div>
    <div id='app-msg-composer'>
         <textarea></textarea>
         <button>Send</button>
    </div>
</div>

#app-container{
    position: fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top: 0px;
    bottom:0px;
}
#app-header{
    position:absolute;
    height:48px;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
}
#app-body{
    position:absolute;
    top:48px;
    bottom: 74px;
    width:100%;
}
#app-msg-composer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    height:74px;
    width:100%;
}
```

As the `textarea` is clicked and comes to focus, the *presence of the virtual keyboard makes the upper half of the page to scroll up(out of the viewport).* This issue is with iPhone only as it is working fine on other android devices. I searched about this issue and found that it is a common issue in iphone because:

**On iPhone, the virtual keyboard's presence does not change the viewport height.**

I tried some solutions from stackoverflow but did not work. How to do this in javascript or css only as I am not using any library?

Comment: CSS without html markup don't help, if possible provide some link of project, or any jsfiddle or code snippet here to recreate the scenerio here.

Comment: you are using too much positioning, i don't see the reason for it, so feel free to post the full page markup and css you are using.

Comment: I am adding textarea and button also but my main concern is with this markup only and in presence of virtual keyboard in iphone.

Comment: The reason for this much positioning is this chatbox has to open like a fullscreen popup with `position:fixed` with body in background. Please suggest if you find some improvement in this markup.

Comment: Is this the whole markup? Then you don't need any positioning, actually shouldn't, mobile devices does not appreciate fixed and absolute positioning much as I checked the last time, and the selected textbox will move up so the user can see what he is typing, you cannot prevent it, you have to make your markup adjustible to screen changes.

Comment: If I give height 100% and keyboard is open than that 100% div should adjust in the remaining area of screen. But in iphones it still takes 100% as full screen. Therefore that div could not adjust in remaining half screen and half of it scrolls up. This is the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165275/discussion-between-munim-munna-and-rohit-agrawal).

Comment: https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill have you checked this? I don't remember correctly if this patch keyboard, but it should cover most of the cases converting vh to px. Therefore you can try 100vh instead of 100% and hope that this plugin would help

Comment: is your textarea inside some cdk-overlay?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the CSS property `position` to `fixed`. That way, it is literally "fixed". It also can not be moved by the screen changing size.

An alternative method is to simply align it to the very top of the screen. This should be done to keep the tip element at the top, the middle in the middle...

Comment: Didn't get you. I am already using `position:fixed`. Can you please explain in detail. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. I will explain. You need to either force an align to the top or to the bottom. This should work. The only case I can think this wont work is that the rendering built into the phone is forcing it up. In this case, you would make a `div` with a height that would vary and push content down when the keyboard is open. @RohitAgrawal

Comment: If none of these work. I can't help you. I could recommend a person try to find a way that works, though. @RohitAgrawal